# How can I add custom widget as Popup menu for ToolButton?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5, qtoolbutton

I have created a custom Widget,it has to be displayed as a popup menu when click on the ToolButton. How I can do this in `Qt 5.1.1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create your custom `QWidgetAction` to add to the popup menu.

This is a sample `QWidgetAction` :

```
#include <QWidgetAction>

class  myCustomWidgetAction: public QWidgetAction
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myCustomWidgetAction(QWidget * parent);

protected:
    QWidget * createWidget(QWidget *parent);

};


myCustomWidgetAction::myCustomWidgetAction(QWidget * parent):QWidgetAction(parent) {
}
QWidget * myCustomWidgetAction::createWidget(QWidget *parent){
    myCustomWidget * widget=new myCustomWidget(parent);
    return widget;
}
```

You can then add your widget to the tool button to be displayed in a popup menu:

```
myCustomWidgetAction * widgetAction   = new myCustomWidgetAction(this);

ui->toolButton->addAction(widgetAction);
```

`myCustomWidget` can be any widget. You can add multiple instances of `myCustomWidgetAction` to the toolButton.

Comment: @SureshR If it's working fine, then mark the answer as accepted. And start accepting all the answers that contributed to solving your other problems/questions. Else chanses are nobody will help you next time you will have a problem ;)